# MySQL Orderby Multiple Variables

Tags: mysql, variables, sql-order-by

I was wondering if I can orderby multiple colums. This is my current code but it gives me an error:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE User='$usersess' ORDER BY Status ASC AND Id DESC AND UNIXtime DESC";
```

Can I have it order the rows in that particular order of importance with the induvidual DESC and ASC to each thing? This a complicated question and I am not sure if I am explaining it well. Let me know if you don't know what I am talking about :)

Thanks

Comment: use comma to separate the columns, not "and" ORDER BY Status ASC, Id DESC, UNIXtime DESC

Comment: @r0ast3d I am getting Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\clientarea\ticketarea.php on line 7 and that Mysql code is on line 6 and gets executed on line 7

Comment: Pls try PeterPeiGuo's answer he got it.

Comment: @r0ast3d Yep. It worked. I can only tick it in 7 min though

Comment: i hope you prevent sql injections

Comment: @BookOfZeus I always do. That was only a snippet.

Comment: @r0ast3d I don't think I can accept two, can I?

Comment: ok good, i said it just in case!

Comment: @BookOfZeus Yep. I do the mysql_escape_string thing but what does it mean? Is there a place I can read up on MySQL injection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it as:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE User='$usersess' ORDER BY Status ASC, Id DESC, UNIXtime DESC";
```